# javascript - Confirm/Cancel before onclick button function

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, submit

I have a button that submits a payment for my website using a function that's defined in an external file. I want to add in an alert box popup for confirming or cancelling the function that's called with the button's `onclick`. I'm familiar with javascript, however, I'm not sure of how exactly to call the function within another if it's defined externally.

What I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var $jj = jQuery.noConflict();
$jj(document).ready(function () {
    $jj('.alertbox').on('click', function () {
       var _this = $jj(this);
       $jj.confirm({
           title: 'Confirm!',
           content: 'Are you sure?',
           buttons: {
            confirm: function review.save(); {

              },
            cancel: function () {

              }
           }
       });
    });
   });
</script>
```

Button `phtml`:

```
<button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Place Order')) ?>" class="button btn-checkout alertbox" onclick="review.save();" ><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?></span></span></button>
```

I know this does not work, as I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: review is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

Do I get rid of the `onclick`?
Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Maybe using a `form` and `input` rather than `button`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
  
  $('#press').on('click', function(){
  var val = validate();
    if(val == true){
    var r = confirm("Submit form!")
    var txt;
    if (r == true) {
    txt = "You pressed OK!";
     //$( "#myform" ).submit(); //use this for submitting the form
} else {
    txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
}
    alert(txt); //this line of code for test reasons
  }
  else{
    alert("input fields empty");
  }
});


function validate(){
    var val = true;
    var teste1 = $("#input1").val();
    var teste2 = $("#input2").val();
    if(teste1== "" || teste1 == null){
      var val = false;
      //some css and jquery to change the input color
    }
    if(teste2 == "" || teste2 == null){
      var val = false;
      //some css and jquery to change the input color
    }
    return val;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id = "myform" action="test.php" method="post">    
 <input type = "text" id ="input1" value = "">
 <input type = "text" id ="input2" value = "">
 <button id = "press" type="button">Click Me!</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: I need to maintain the use of `review.save();` function, which is where my problem lies.

Comment: What does the function do?

Comment: Its a function that saves the payment information on onepage checkout and redirects the customer to PayPal. (I'm using Magento)

Comment: How do you want a form to be submitted after you have redirected?

Comment: One possible solution for what you want to do, use ajax.